# nodejs mailparser parsing same message multiple times

Tags: node.js, email

I'm using both the `inbox` and `mailparser` npm modules to read and parse emails from a mailbox.

I'm having some trouble with duplicate messages being parsed. currently what is happening is:

The emails are being dropped into the correct mailbox as you would expect from an email server. Then they are being picked up by `inbox` in my node.js application. Then they are being piped to `mailparser` and being parsed.

That is working correctly. The problem is that when I send a second email I just get the first one again. Sometimes I get multiple, but I haven't figured out what causes that.

```
let _inbox      = require( "inbox"      );
let _MailParser = require( "mailparser" ).MailParser;

let parser  = new _MailParser();
let mail    = _inbox.createConnection( false, "mail.myemailserver.com", {
  auth: {
    user: "email@myemailserver.com",
    pass: "mypasswordthatissostrongnoonewilleverguessit:)"
  }
});

mail.on( "new", ( message ) => {
  console.log( message.UID, message.title );
  db_insert( DB.collection( "email_ids" ), { _id: message.UID } ).then( () => {
    mail.createMessageStream( message.UID ).pipe( parser );
  });
});

parser.on( "end", ( message ) => {
  // This works the first time, I get the correct message.
  // The second time this gets called I just get the first message again.
});
```

My spidey senses are telling me it has something to do with the fact I have no idea how `streams` and `pipe` work. It's also worth noting that this is the first time I've used either of these libraries and I may have missed something.

[mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser)
[inbox](https://github.com/pipedrive/inbox)

I'm using MongoDB and it throws a wobbly if you try to insert the same `_id` twice, but this isn't complaining at all. Which reinforces my suspicion about `streams` and `pipe`.

I'm using es6 with the babel transpiler.

## Update

I no longer need an answer to this question. I decided to look for a different library. I'm now using `mail-notifier`.

Just in case someone is interested. This is how I solved the problem.

```
let _notifier = require( "mail-notifier" );

let imap = {
  user    : "email@myemailserver.com",
  password: "mypasswordthatissostrongnoonewilleverguessit:)",
  host    : "mail.mymailserver.com"
};

_notifier( imap ).on( "mail", ( mail ) => {
  // process email
}).start();
```

I'd still be interested to know what was causing the problem with the other approach, but it's not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The reason is that you have to create new instance of MailParser each time you run through a cycle.

```
let _MailParser = require( "mailparser" ).MailParser;

mail.on( "new", ( message ) => {

  parser = new _MailParser();

  // do your stuff

  parser.on( "end", ( message ) => {

     // finished

  });
}
```